# UINavigationController flow swift

Tags: swift, networking, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I am working on an app that produces a checkout flow.
I have SelectionViewControllers for each item and one final InvoiceViewController.

Here is  look at my app delegate as it was before.  I’ve since learned that it is not a good idea to have the app delegate performing all of these responsibilities.

```
  var window: UIWindow?

var nextVCIndex = 1
var vcArray = [ECSelectionViewController]()
var items = [ECItem]()


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    ECNetworkingHelper.sharedInstance.fetchCurrentFix { (data, error) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            let nav = UINavigationController()

            self.items = data
            //create my selectionViewControllers
            for item in data {
                if let selectionVC = ECSelectionViewController(item: item) {
                    self.vcArray.append(selectionVC)
                }
            }

            nav.viewControllers = [self.vcArray[0]]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dataLoaded", object: nil)


            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = nav
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        })
    }

    return true
}
```

I’ve worked on moving the networking to the navigation controller.

So my question is how to setup my navigation controller and organize my code to produce the same functionality that I had. 
-which was fetching item data from data source. - creating a selection view controller for each item.  and loading them in a navigation controller for a user to cycle through.(next button on the nav bar to proceed to next item)  once the user hits the final selection view controller. I initialize an invoice view controller.

[image]

Also to note.  I want to show a loading view controller while the data is downloading.  once done then load all the selection view controllers for the user to navigate through.

- here is my current attempt, on the loading view controller I call my fetch data function and then update the nav accordingly
- not happy with it because instead of pushing a new view controller i am popping them off.  don’t like the way it is shifting left
- in short I want to follow proper standards, keep the code clean and make satisfy my UI

---

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //Show Loading Indicator
    let nav = ECNavigationController()
    let loadingVC = ECLoadingViewController()
    nav.viewControllers = [loadingVC]

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()



    return true
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're making this a *lot* harder than it needs to be. Are you using Storyboards to define your views & controllers? You shouldn't need to create any of them yourself. I suggest you have a look at some of the tutorials.

Comment: From what you want to achieve, it looks like you just need a single `UICollectionViewController` that does the networking and displays the results. Each image would take up the full screen so you can swipe to the next (although would you want that on an iPad too?). You would just show a UIActivityIndicator while the networking is happening.

Comment: Nope I built the views programmatically

Comment: So why not move to using a Storyboard? It will make your life much easier.